# how to get a screenshot of web application

Tags: browser, screenshot

Google had this deal on youtube about sharing an issue on their site by leaving feedback. When you clicked on it, it took a screenshot of the current page. How can I do that in my application so I can see the error my users are having?

Comment: IMO you have to have a Google toolbar installed to do that, if possible at all as you say.

Comment: If you tell people what framework/language/etc you are using you it will help them to give you an answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: javascript of course, and I don't care what framework. I just want to know if it's possible with ANY framework

Answer (score 4):

With Usersnap (http://usersnap.com), you can get screenshots from your users. They don't have to install any plugin or browser extension and it works with all major browsers (read: including Internet Explorer!).

Installing usersnap is as easy as installing Google analytics, i.e. adding a small JavaScript snippet to your page.

P.S: I'm a co founder of usersnap - if you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I'm curious, where does the rendering of the captured screenshot happen? On the browser or do you render at the server?

Comment: Hi Elmar, to get accurate screenshots you need to render on the server :-) Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey @Gregor, what happens if wan't to use the feedback tool on a web app that needs users to login.
Let's say Facebook wanted to allow users to send feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.NET, you could do something like this (see the *"Calling with the IHttpHandler Method"*):
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95439/Get-ASP-NET-C-2-0-Website-Thumbnail-Screenshot

Then, your button would submit a request to the handler (possibly via AJAX), and you could either store the answer using the handler itself, or do a second postback with the results to your processing form.